# FabricJS circle to show radius

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs in my project but I want to show the radius of the circle on the fabric. Could I ask how to do this. There could be up to 20 circles which I will need this information for and the circles will have controls on so they can be expanded with the radius text adjusting to compensate.

http://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/a3q5c40r/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fill: "",
    radius: 40,
    hasControls: false, 
    hasRoatatingPoint: false,
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1  

});

canvas.add(circle);
```

If this isn't possible, can a user set the radius via an input?

Comment: What do you want to do with the display of the radius?  Do you want to display it below the canvas in a text box or something?

Comment: Sorry Ben for my late reply. Stephen's comment below is what i needed, i think i would have preferred a text input rather than a slider, but its better than i could have worked out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. In the example below I have a button that ads a group to the canvas of a circle and text box. When one of those groups are selected a range input appears that lets you change the radius. on change we reach in to the group and update the text and radius of the circle.

```js
window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

function getCircleGroup(radius = 40) {
  var text = new fabric.Text(radius.toString(), {
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
  });
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
      fill: "",
      radius: radius,
      hasControls: false, 
      hasRoatatingPoint: false,
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 1  

  });
  
  return new fabric.Group([ circle, text ], {
       lockScalingX: true,
       lockScalingY: true,
  });

}

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var group = getCircleGroup();
  canvas.add(group);
  canvas.setActiveObject(group);
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('object:selected', (o) => {
  var r = document.querySelector('.radiusChange');
  r.style.display = 'block';
  r.querySelector('input').value = o.radius;
})

canvas.on('selection:cleared', () => {
 var r = document.querySelector('.radiusChange');
 r.style.display = 'none';
});

var radiusChanger = document.querySelector('.radiusChange input')
radiusChanger.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  var group = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var top = group.top;
  var left = group.left;
  group.item(0).setRadius(parseInt(e.target.value));
  group.item(1).text = e.target.value;
  group._calcBounds();
  group._updateObjectsCoords();
  group.top = top;
  group.left = left;
  canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button>add circle</button>
<div class="radiusChange" style="display:none;">
<br />change radius: <input type="range" max=100 min=10 step=1 /></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
```